# Can't find variable letter in React Native setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I tried using `setState` in a `TextInput` like so:

```
class AppS extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      ShowText: '',
      letter: ''
    };
  }
  render(){
    return( 
      <View>  
        <TextInput style ={{color: "green"}}
          onChangeText = {(letter)=>this.setState({ letter })}>
        </TextInput>
        <Text style = {styleForApps.fon}> {this.state.letter} </Text>
        <Text style = {styleForApps.body}> {this.state.ShowText} </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

When I experiment with `setState` like this:

```
onChangeText = {(txt)=>this.setState({ letter: txt })}>
```

It works well. But when I changed it to:

```
onChangeText = {(txt)=>this.setState({ letter })}>
```

It always give a error "Can't find variable letter". I thought that `setState` point the parameter in parenthesis that should be defined by `txt`.

Can you explain please, I don't understand how exactly it passes the value to `letter`.

Answer (score 7):

You're attempting to use [shorthand property definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions). This ES6 feature allows you to only specify the key if the key and value **are the same**. It does *not* take the value of the argument. That means when you do:

```
this.setState({
  letter
});
```

It means this:

```
this.setState({
  letter: letter
});
```

Because it desugars so that the key and value are the same. This then reports the error because `letter` isn't defined. You could do:

```
(letter) => this.setState({ letter })
```

This works because you name the argument `letter`, not `txt`.

Answer (score 0):

`onChangeText` takes a function and passes the text that the user enters into that function, in your example you're naming that user input as `txt` but inside of `setState` you're not assigning this user input to `letter`, what you're doing is specifying `this.setState({letter})` which gets translated into `this.setState({letter: letter})` and because you don't have a variable named letter you get an error